# Javascript: Convert list of values to set of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, typescript

I am fetching data from server..

Data returned from server is..

```
{
 Increase: true,
Decrease: false,
Like:true,
Unlike: true,
Others: false,
Limits:true
}
```

Below is what i get after Ngrx service dispatch

console.log('this.data=' +data);

```
this.data= [object Object]
```

Now after doing console.log('Object.keys(data)='+ Object.keys(data));

```
Object.keys(data)= Increase,Decrease,Like,Unlike,Others,Limits
```

How can i get same set of data like below after console.log

```
  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

so that after JSON.stringify.. i can get that same data like below

```
[{"description":"Increase"},{"description":"Decrease"},{"description":"Like"},{"description":"Unlike"},{"description":"Others"},{"description":"Limits"},]
```

Comment: I suggest that you start using a comma to separate elements in console.log: `console.log('this.data=', data);` Seeing the actual object instead of [object Object] is much more useful.

Comment: `Object.entries()` + `Array.prototype.map()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take `entries` and then map it:

```js
var obj={ Increase: true, Decrease: false, Like:true, Unlike: true, Others: false, Limits:true};

var result = Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v}));

var result2 = Object.entries(obj).map(([k])=>({'Description':k}));

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#:~:text=Description,properties%20of%20the%20object%20manually.) then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the result array, this is a working snippet:

```js
const obj = {
  Increase: true,
  Decrease: false,
  Like: true,
  Unlike: true,
  Others: false,
  Limits: true,
};

//const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => ({ description: key }));

const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => ({ [key]: obj[key]}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```